# Bookshelf relations aren't working as expected

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js

I have 4 tables simplified as follows:

**Tables**

```
event:     id, location_id  
location:  id  
user:      id  
eventUser: event_id, user_id
```

**Relations**

```
Event hasOne Location  
Event belongsToMany Users

Location belongsTo Event

User belongsToMany Events

EventUser belongsToMany Events  
EventUser belongsToMany Users
```

**I want to get Events with Locations given a User id**

One example of what I've tried:

```
EventUser.forge().where({user_id: 1}).fetchAll({withRelated: ['Event', 'Event.Location']})
```

But I can't get it to return any events.

Is my set up correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was

`User.forge().where({id: 1}).fetchAll({withRelated: ['Event.Location']})` and then drilling down through the models to get what I needed. I thought I could cut out one step by using EventUser instead of User.